# How to stretch in height column

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make my column fill in height the rest of empty space, I tried using flexible, sizedbox etc. but I keep getting this error. Am I doing something wrong?

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#b1e29 relayoutBoundary=up1
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

```
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: double.infinity,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(widget.name,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                              maxLines: 2,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                          Container(
                                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                              child: Text(
                                                  widget.description,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 16.0)),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

Comment: Please provide full codes, a part of code is not enough infomation

Comment: which type  of UI  Create can you send  UI

Comment: Did you try using Expanded?

Comment: Yes, but get this error `The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.`

Comment: are you get BottomOverflow error?

Comment: Parent widget is stack

Comment: @squnk can you provide result screen?

Comment: I think you need to provide the `SingleChildScrollView` with some height. As I can see that you have provided a `Container` widget with no height. Please provide some height and then check!!!

Comment: @AloysiusSamuel because I want the container to fill, then automatically make Scroll work if full height is reached

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: double.infinity,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.name,
            style:
                const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            maxLines: 2,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Container(
            child: Text(
              widget.description,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```